# cancelling std::thread using native_handle() + pthread_cancel()

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, pthreads, stdthread

I am converting a previous thread wrapper around pthreads to std::thread.
However c++11 does not have any way to cancel the thread. I REQUIRE, nonetheless, to cancel threads since they may be performing a very lengthy task inside an external library.

I was considering using the native_handle that gives me pthread_id in my platform. I'm using gcc 4.7 in Linux (Ubuntu 12.10). The idea would be:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    cout << "Hello, world!" << endl;

    auto lambda = []() {
        cout << "ID: "<<pthread_self() <<endl;
        while (true) {
            cout << "Hello" << endl;
            this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(2));
        }
    };

    pthread_t id;
    {
        std::thread th(lambda);

        this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(1));

        id = th.native_handle();
        cout << id << endl;
        th.detach();
    }
    cout << "cancelling ID: "<< id << endl;

    pthread_cancel(id);

    cout << "cancelled: "<< id << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The thread is canceled by an exception thrown by pthreads.

My question is:

Will there be any problem with this approach (besides not being portable)?

Comment: pthreads can't throw exceptions. It's a C library, and there are no exceptions in C.

Comment: I do not know the exact technical details how an exception is thrown but one is... just try to add "try{code}catch(...){}" inside the lambda and a sleep at the end of main() and you will get "FATAL: exception not rethrown".

Comment: Just got a segmentation fault by adding a sleep at the end of main()... something is wrong with this strategy :(

Comment: Please note that cancelling threads has all sorts of side effects including memory leaks. If you can afford not to, don't cancel threads. Ever. It is much better (and not so hard) to use an `atomic<bool>` variable per thread that you would read in your while condition instead.

Comment: I understand that, unfortunately that would mean changing a third party's library or waiting for several minutes until the atomic variable is checked. With my previous implementation (using pthreads directly) I have never seen memory leaks (at least valgrind does not complain...)... it could just be luck though. The purpose of canceling threads is to exit the application in a controlled manner.

Comment: If your purpose to exit the application, you don't have to worry about leaking memory.  It is cleaned up as the application exits.  You only need to worry about leaking any resources that would live beyond your application (e.g. an inter-process semaphore).  Your application may not own any such resources.  If all this is the case, I'd say your original code is good to go.

Comment: @JoãoLeal: The exception is most likely thrown by the `std::thread` object. Pthread cancellation usually works by raising a signal against the thread; it's possible that `std::thread` interacts with that in some way.

Comment: the moment you hit "detach" you lose control over the thread anyways, don't detach it and do a join before exit should not throw exception

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, I don't think that you will not have additional problems than:

- not being portable
- having to program _very_very_ carefully that all objects of the cancelled thread are destroyed...

For example, the Standard says that when a thread ends variables will be destroyed. If you cancel a thread this will be much harder for the compiler, if not impossible.

I would, therefore recommend *not* to cancel a thread if you can somehow avoid it. Write a standard polling-loop, use a condition variable, listen on a signal to interrupt reads and so on -- and end the thread regularly.

Comment: canceling a thread simply causes the thread to exit as if an exception was thrown and never caught... so I guess that normal memory handling will still work. Unfortunately the presented code is NOT OK... there will be a segmentation fault if a sleep is added at the end of main. I do not know the cause yet... :(

Comment: @joao-leal: really, "as if an exception was thrown"? I can imagine it, but it sounds difficult to implement. I find "undefined behaviour" rather more straightforward. Can you point me to where this is mentioned in the Standard? Do I remember correctly that an uncaught exception in a thread passes by unnoticed -- that, for e.g., it does not call `terminate()` on the whole program?

Comment: nothing to do with the c++ standard but the way pthreads works: http://cursuri.cs.pub.ro/~apc/2003/resources/pthreads/uguide/concep30.htm

Comment: @joao-leal: I see. Thank you. But C++11 may work in a completely different way then pthreads. If you use pthreads, then the pthreads spec is relevant. If you use C++11, that spec is relevant.