# Returning std::pair<vector<int>, double> with phtread_exit

Tags: c++, pthreads

I want to return a `std::pair<std::vector<int>, double>` from a thread.

The setup is the following:

```
void* thread_run(void *);
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

     std::pair<std::vector<int>, double> value;

     pthread_t t;
     pthread_create(&t, NULL, thread_run, NULL);

     // wait
     void* out;
     pthread_join(t, &out);

     value = *(std::pair<std::vector<int>, double> *)out;
     free(out);

     use(value);
}

void* thread_run(void* arg) {
    std::pair<std::vector<int>, double> * out = (std::pair<std::vector<int>, double>*)
        malloc(sizeof(std::pair<std::vector<int>, double>));

    out->first  = calc1();
    out->second = calc2();

    pthread_exit(out);
}
```

The problem is that I create a memory leak. Valgrind reports that:

1. A conditional jump or move depends on unitialised values and points to the allocation `out->first = calc1();`
2. Unitialized value was created by a heap allocation and points to the **malloc** line.

I am using gcc 5.4.0 & C++ 11 and the pthread library. I need to use pthread. How do I return C++ STL containers correctly to avoid the memory leak.

Comment: Use `new`, not `malloc`.

Comment: My understanding is that there's no cancellation mechanism for std::thread. I need a cancellation mechanism.

Further, if going the malloc route, would I have to give up on returning std containers from the thread?

Comment: You should giving up on creating _any_ C++ object with malloc.

Comment: Use `std::thread`. For cancellation mechanisms, do `pthread_cancel(std::thread::native_handle())` [Here is a example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13531241/cancelling-stdthread-using-native-handle-pthread-cancel)

Comment: Thank you all for your valuable input, I can only select one answer but all of your feedback has been very valuable. I wish there was a way in SO to reward everyone who contributed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just return a pointer to it, just like anything else. Don't use `malloc`, use `new`. Remember to call `delete` with proper type.

```
#include <vector>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <iostream>

void* thread_run(void *);
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

     std::pair<std::vector<int>, double> value;

     pthread_t t;
     pthread_create(&t, NULL, thread_run, NULL);

     // wait
     void* out;
     pthread_join(t, &out);

     std::pair<std::vector<int>, double> *pntvalue = 
        static_cast<std::pair<std::vector<int>, double>*>(out);
     value = *pntvalue;
     delete pntvalue;

    std::cout << std::get<1>(value) << std::endl;
}

void* thread_run(void* arg) {
    std::pair<std::vector<int>, double> *out = new std::pair<std::vector<int>, double>{};
    out->first  = std::vector<int>{1};
    out->second = 2;
    return out;
}
```

> if going the malloc route, would I have to give up on returning std containers from the thread?

Not at all, but remember to properly call constructors and destructors of your objects. It would be something along:

```
#include <vector>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <iostream>

void* thread_run(void *);
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

     std::pair<std::vector<int>, double> value;

     pthread_t t;
     pthread_create(&t, NULL, thread_run, NULL);

     // wait
     void* out;
     pthread_join(t, &out);

     std::pair<std::vector<int>, double> *pntvalue = 
        static_cast<std::pair<std::vector<int>, double>*>(out);
     value = *pntvalue;
     pntvalue->~pair<std::vector<int>, double>();
     free(pntvalue);

    std::cout << std::get<1>(value) << std::endl;
}

void* thread_run(void* arg) {
    std::pair<std::vector<int>, double> *out = static_cast<
        std::pair<std::vector<int>, double> *>(malloc(sizeof(std::pair<std::vector<int>, double>)));
    new (out) std::pair<std::vector<int>, double>{};
    out->first  = std::vector<int>{1};
    out->second = 2;
    return out;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your program has undefined behavior, because you allocate memory for `out`, but never construct an object in this memory.

Then with `out->first  = calc1();` you try to access a member of the non-existent object, which causes undefined behavior.

If you need to manually manage memory, then you need to use `new`:

```
auto out = new std::pair<std::vector<int>, double>{};
```

and later delete it with

```
delete static_cast<std::pair<std::vector<int>, double>*>(out);
```

Note that you need to delete the pointer with the same type that it was created with. You might want to do the cast immediately when returning.

In C++ using `malloc` is almost always wrong and you should be using `std::thread` which comes with a proper portable C++ interface, instead of the POSIX-only C interface that pthread offers.

Answer (score 1):

How about this: don't allocate on the heap.

You successfully create a pair named `value` in `main()` with automatic storage duration.  Just use that.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

#include <pthread.h>

void* thread_run(void *);

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
     std::pair<std::vector<int>, double> value;

     pthread_t t;
     pthread_create(&t, NULL, thread_run, &value);

     // Wait.  Do not need to retrieve results, which are available in `value`.
     pthread_join(t, nullptr);

     std::cout << "Results: " << value.first.at(1) << "; " << value.second << '\n';
}

void* thread_run(void* arg) {
    std::pair<std::vector<int>, double>& out = *static_cast<std::pair<std::vector<int>, double>*>(arg);

    out.first  = std::vector<int>{{1, 2, 3}};
    out.second = 42.0;

    pthread_exit(arg);
}
```

[Runnable example on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/aa5da0201e266a89)